# Opening firefox with Batch

Tags: batch-file, firefox, cmd

I have a .bat that contains a command that check if firefox is open before running a second command that run a timeout.

```
@echo off
set programName=firefox.exe
tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq %programName%" 2>NUL | find /I /N "%programName%">NUL
if "%errorlevel%"=="0" goto delayloop
if "%errorlevel%"=="1"  start %programName% goto delayloop

:delayloop
timeout /t 600 /nobreak
goto loop
```

The problem is that the command open firefox with 2 new tab that are goto.com and delayloop.com, instead of using the firefox default which is : "show my windows and tabs from last time".

Any idea how to "tell" CMD that `goto delayloop` aren't tabs to open in firefox. 
Despite understanding `goto delayloop` as news adress in tabs, the .bat always goes to the next command `delayloop.

How can I change the go to prevent this 2 news tabs to be opened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Batch does exactly, what you tell it to do:

```
 if "%errorlevel%"=="1"  start %programName% goto delayloop
```

If errorlevel is one, then start a program `(%programName%`) with Parameters (`goto` and `delayloop`

IF supports only one command, so you have to "group" your commands (several commands in parantheses are logically treated as one command):

```
if "%errorlevel%"=="1" (
  start %programName%
  goto :delayloop
)
```

or as a one-liner:

```
if "%errorlevel%"=="1"  (start %programName% & goto delayloop)
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to use:

```
if "%errorlevel%"=="1" (
  start %programName% 
  goto delayloop
 )
```

else batch will consider goto and delayloop as arguments.